# Adding SQL Server Reporting Service to an existing SQL Server 2019 instance

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

Can anyone help please?
I have an existing SQL Server 2019 instance to which I am trying to add Reporting Server.
The Installation Centre takes me to a link on the internet where I can download the Reporting Services installation media. On trying to do the install, it asks for a Product Key and does not let me proceed without entering a key.

We normally get our software from VLSC so I thought that using the Product Key for SQL 2019 engine from VLSC is what I would need. On logging into VLSC however, there is no key required for SQL 2019 Enterprise Edition per core that comes up.

Also, I did a search for Reporting Services and that doesn't come up as a product at all.

So I'm not sure how to proceed.

There is no Reporting Services product for me to download from VLSC and no Product key for SQL 2019 engine to use for the Reporting Services install media downloaded from the internet. How do I proceed with the downloaded install media please?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for: [Find the product key for SQL Server Reporting Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/find-reporting-services-product-key-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16).

Basically, if you run the SQL Server 2019 installer again, on the machine running your instance, I believe it should tell you what the product key is that it was installed with. You should be able to copy and re-use that key for installing SSRS.

Comment: @JD thank you for your help as always. The problem I have is that the SQL instance product key is embeded in the media, as it was from VLSC. So I don't have the key for the SQL instance. I just wanted to check if there's anything else I should consider before I go back to our Licensing team to let them know. Just to be sure that I haven't missed anything on my part. Thanks again.

Comment: @PTL_SQL No problem. My understanding is that if you re-run the installer for the SQL Server instance (even if you need to re-download the install media), it'll show you what that embedded key is though.

Comment: oh...ok, I'll try that and feed back, thank you so much @JD

Comment: Hi @JD, just to say no joy in getting the embedded product key yet. I've left it with the licensing team to get back to me. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @PTL_SQL ah ok, best of luck!

Comment: @JD, I got it in the end from this link:  https://jacktracey.co.uk/sql/finding-the-license-key-for-sql-server-reporting-services/ it was the Maintenance page and Edition upgrade menu option that I needed from the Installation Centre. Thanks again for your help, always very much appreciated.